# Adding keyword metadata to images in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, metadata, photosframework

I've been wrestling with finding a way to add keyword metadata to images in iOS. I've scoured the internet and stackoverflow but haven't found anything specific to adding keywords to images in iOS. I've seen that different applications like Photoshop and Aperture allow you to do this type of thing so, the capability for images is there in general, **but is there a way to achieve this in iOS?**

Specifically, is it possible to create a new key/value pair and nest it within the image metadata?

Comment: Do you know about EXIF?

Comment: Yeah, but haven't seen a way to add a keyword to it, only ways to hijack preexisting unused keywords.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the [CGImageProperties reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/EXIF_Dictionary_Keys). As you can see, you are allowed to add EXIF dictionary information to an image. This is exactly how Photoshop and Aperture do it. The ImageIO framework will give you the means to write into the EXIF dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, but how do you add a new keyword? It seems to only be able to be used with the preexisting keywords (ex. kCGImagePropertyExifExposureTime). I'd like to add something like `[metadata setObject:@[@"Bubbles", @"Paris", @"With Friends"] forKey:@"Keywords"];`

Comment: @WiseOlMan i have same requirement , if you have any solution kindly share it here

Comment: A 'keywords' property already exists in IPTC metadata. Look for `kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords` in `ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h`. You can also create your own section. Look at `CGImageMetadataRegisterNamespaceForPrefix` function in `ImageIO/CGImageMetadata.h`.